# Apache2 mod_substitute broken page

Tags: apache2, reverse-proxy

I all,
I'm using Apache2 (2.4.56) as a reverse proxy for a proprietary web application developed in .net.
The Apache configuration uses a substitution to convert some external address references: http to https

```
        <Location /app/>
                RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding

                AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html text/css application/javascript text/plain application/json application/x-javascript
                SubstituteMaxLineLength 20m
                Substitute "s|http://|https://|ni"

                Header edit Location ^http://example.com/app/(.*$) "https://example.com/app/$1"

                ProxyPass http://x.x.x.x:80/app/
                ProxyPassReverse http://x.x.x.x:x/app/

                Header always append X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"

        </Location>
```

sometimes it happens that the application pages are not loaded completely on the browser which remains waiting until the timeout.

It doesn't appear to be a resource or connection pool configuration issue

Has anyone solved a similar problem?